# Init inside of UIViewController never called

Tags: swift

I would like to use an `init` inside of my view controller in order to initialize some properties. I've tried creating a default `init` and overriding the existing ones in `UIViewController`, and everything compiles without error, but none of them get called. Why is that?

These are my current inits, none are called.

```
init(){
    cameraSession = AVCaptureSession()
    cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
    captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as AVCaptureDevice

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle!) {
    cameraSession = AVCaptureSession()
    cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
    captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as AVCaptureDevice
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    cameraSession = AVCaptureSession()
    cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
    captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as AVCaptureDevice

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: How are you creating your view controller object code or xib, if code then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon how you're creating your view controller object.

If you're using storyboard or xib then this method will be called

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

}
```

Comment: Turns out I had not set my initial view controller

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an initialiser, try initialising the properties with default values using the design-and-call pattern (see http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#SECdefineandcall and http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_computed_initializer), like this:

```
class ViewController {
    var cameraSession: AVCaptureSession = {
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
        return session
    }()

    var captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as AVCaptureDevice
}
```

Then there's no need for an initialiser at all!